# configuring TTL from 1800 sec to 86400 sec on Ubuntu, nginx server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, nameserver, ttl, digital-ocean

I deployed an app to Digital Ocean Ubuntu server. The app is running on NGINX.

My Domain registar sent me the messages that "TTL can't be less than 86400 sec on nameservers" It is currently 1800 sec by default from Digital Ocean.

Can someone advice me on how I can configure the TTL settings from 1800 sec to 86400 sec.

There must be some way to access the settings through terminal?

I'm rather new to all this so any advice or guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The TTL for the nameservers of your domain is configured in the DNS records of your domain.  You can determine where your authoritative DNS records are by executing `nslookup -type=soa domain.com`; you must replace domain.com with your current domain. Once you have identified the authoritative DNS server, you will need to go to that service, likely your registrar or local DNS service, and change the NS records within the zone to increase the TTL from 1800 to 86400.